# Where is the "fix" button on Windows 7 Photo Viewer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-photo-viewer

When I click on a photo in **Vista** I get a fix button:

[image]

When I click on a photo in **Windows 7** I don't get a fix button:

[image]

I used to use this fix button often to fix red-eye and alter the brightness quickly, and the auto-saving was so fast. If I can't get "Windows Photo Viewer" to do this, I'll have to use [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) again to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The photo viewer included in Windows 7 doesn't have this feature, but you can install the [Windows Photo Gallery from Windows Live](http://download.live.com/photogallery) to get it back.

More specifically, you need the 2009 version of Windows Live Photo Gallery, downloadable [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-live/download-windows-essentials#wetabs=wl2009)

Comment: I believe this answer has become defunct. In short, Windows removed the fix button. Some more elaboration and complaining here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/windows-live-photo-gallery-2011-no-longer-has-fix/c6c9d7fd-5a4d-42c0-8aab-da302b2f7061